# "Admin module" taking over Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I have an "admin" module and I want it to serve "dynamic controllers", i.e. to provide a default behaviour for controllers which don't really exist ("virtual controllers").

I've invented a lightweight messaging mechanism for loose communication between modules. I'd like to use it such that when e.g.

```
?r=admin/users/index
```

is requested, it will call the "virtual controller" "UserController" of AdminModule, which would, by default, use this messaging mechanism to notify the real module "UsersModule" it can answer to the request.

I thought about simulating this behaviour in AdminModule::init(), but at that point I have no way of deciding whether the action can be processed by a real controller or not, or at least I don't know how to do it.

This is because of the way Yii works: bottom-up, the controller is the one that renders the view AND the application layout (or the module's, if it exists), for example. I don't think the module even has a word to say about handling a given controller+action or not.

To recap, I'm looking for a kind of CWebModule::missingController($controllerId,$actionId), just like CController::missingAction($actionId), or a workaround to simulate that.

That would possibly be in CWebModule::init() or somewhere where I can find out

1. whether the controller actually exists, in which case it's his job to handle it
2. the $actionID and $controllerID
3. whether the module $controllerID exists (I didn't type it wrong, in r=admin/users/index, "users" is the actual module, as specified in the application's config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/7569-admin-module-taking-over/page__view__findpost__p__38399